# Show operator is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Not from homework, but practice problems for an exam.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, it seems like it should be pretty simple. Let $X \neq \{0\}$ denote a complex normed vector space, and
assume that the operator $T : D(T) ⊂ X → X $ is closed. Let $λ ∈ C$. Show
that the operator $T − λI$ is closed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think this is fairly doable by just looking at convergent sequences in the graph.

Comment: Theorem 4.13.3 in Kreyszig, I mostly wanted to see how to structure the argument.

Comment: To show that $T-\lambda I$ is closed, you take an arbitrary sequence in its graph, convergent in $X\times X$, and show that the limit lies in the graph. To use the fact that $T$ is closed, you can manipulate the sequence so it lies in the graph of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $D(T)$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n:=(T - \lambda I)x_n \to y$.

We have to show that $x \in D(T)$ and $(T - \lambda I)x=y$.

From $Tx_n = y_n+ \lambda x_n \to y + \lambda x$, we see, since $T$ is closed, that $x \in D(T)$ and $Tx=y + \lambda x$, hence $(T - \lambda I)x=y$.

Comment: Thank you, convergence always confuses me